# Could you explain what happens with Struts2 web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, action, ognl

An action class

```java
public class IndexAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
private int submitPage;
//getter-setter
```

a method

```
public String execute() {

        // this means that session is NEW
        if(!session.containsKey("progres")) {

            System.out.println("NEW session");
            System.out.println("level " + 1);
            session.put("level", 1);
            return SUCCESS;
        }
```

jsp page

```
<% Integer level = (Integer)session.getAttribute("level"); %>
<c:set var="level" scope="request" value='<%=session.getAttribute("level")%>' />
<!--<c:out value="Level: ${level}"/>-->

<h2>Task <c:out value="${level}"/></h2>
<s:form action="index">
<s:hidden name="submitPage" value="%{level}" />
...
```

When I first time visit this page it renders to this

```
<!--Level: 1-->

<h2>Task 1.</h2>


<form id="index" name="index" action="/Struts2HiberQuize_2/index.action" method="post">
<table class="wwFormTable">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitPage" value="0" id="index_submitPage"/>
    ...
```

Why hidden fild contains value="0", it must be value="1" ? This happens if page accesed first time. Next times that hidden value corresponds to var="level" as should.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but also not sure why you don't just set `submitPage` to the value you want.

Comment: Because I must send value to action class only with form submit if I understand correctly.

Comment: You don't understand correctly; if you hit the JSP via an action (which you should) the action properties are used as form values--that's pretty much the concept behind the Struts 2 view layer.

Comment: To expand on Roman's correct explanation, `%{level}` isn't meaningful on its own. You could use `%{#session.level}` or `%{#attr.level}` to access session-scoped values, but this seems like a strange workaround when you could just set `submitPage`.

Comment: Yes, this value can be set in the method. In any case, now working as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value is populated from the hidden field `name` attribute bound to action's `int` attribute that contains `0` value. You don't have a value in the `value` attribute because your expression returns nothing i.e. don't have `level` in the value stack.

That is how it works: the tag reads the value from the `value` attribute and if it's `null` then it uses a value from the `name` attribute as OGNL expression. After the expression is evaluated the returned value rendered to the `value` attribute of the `input` tag.